# Image not fitting properly into Circular Image View

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I've a rectangular image, which I want to display into a circular border image view:
I made a drawable like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
    <solid android:color="#41ba7a" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dip"
        android:color="#f9f9f9" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

I'm using it inside a ImageButton :

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/service_image_on_orderpage"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_circular_border_imageview"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

This looks like this :

[image]

But when I load the image into it then it appears like this :

[image]

It is not completely covering the ImageButton. I want that the picture loaded should cover the ImageButton in circular way.

I've tried changing all possible options of `android:scaleType`, but nothing suits the requirement, I even have tried changing the ImageButton into ImageView but still the problem persists.

Please help.

Comment: Has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39423549/6816052

Comment: Use This Library https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: @NikunjParadva : can't use this, because I've to change ImageButton at many places in my project.

Comment: @Amit Upadhyay Instead of `ImageButton` take `ImageView` as `Nikunj` say and then set it.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay I think Circular Imagebutton is not Possible but Use Imageview I hope This  Library is works for you

Comment: @Ironman : I've tried using ImageView also(mentioned in second last line of question), but the result is same.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay Use those library n then check https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay post that code which `Nikunj` has mention..and make sure that you have add dependency for that.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay Your Problem is solved or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Amit Upadhyay you should try this awesome library for a fast circular ImageView perfect for profile images.This is based on RoundedImageView from Vince Mi which itself is based on techniques recommended by Romain Guy

**For using this library you need to add dependency in your gradle like below:**

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
```

**and for its usage add the widget in your layout xml file like below:**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/profile_image"
android:layout_width="96dp"
android:layout_height="96dp"
android:src="@drawable/profile"
app:civ_border_width="2dp"
app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

***this will help you for sure!!!***

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/service_image_on_orderpage"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_circular_border_imageview"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

and after this also if you are getting same problem change the scaleType to another.

Comment: as mentioned in the question I've tried every possible options for `scaleType` and nothing seems to help

Comment: to load image what are you using ? android:src or glide?